# AngularJS adding array to cookie store

Tags: arrays, angularjs, cookies

The snippet is as follows

```
function CartForm($scope,$cookieStore) {
$scope.invoice = {
    items: [{
        qty: 10,
        description: 'item',
        cost: 9.95}]
};
//want to add the above array to cookie store here 
}
```

How can i put the above array into cookiestore, and later access it and bind it ?

Comment: Put:`$cookieStore.put('invoice', $scope.invoice);`Get:`return $cookieStore.get('invoice');`

Comment: hello @MohammadSepahvand yes i tried that. Check this JSFiddle http://jsfiddle.net/slav123/75m7e/3/ . the code is take from that. When i add $cookieStore to the CartForm, it stops functioning. I tried adding an external resource of the angular cookies , it still did not work.

Comment: see my answer, it has a working plunk.

Comment: yes its working fine now. Just had to put it up on localhost. thanks a lot :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The standard way to put and get data in cookies is this:

Put:`$cookieStore.put('invoice', $scope.invoice)`;

Get: `return $cookieStore.get('invoice')`;

This will require a refrence to ngCookies in your app, and also the external angular-cookies script. See [this plunk](http://plnkr.co/edit/BLJ83zdLkdEgYSFgkFoK), see the cookie getting logged in the console.

Comment: thanks a lot ! It works great on plunk. But does not seem to be working when I run it on my system. The console returns undefined .

Comment: Did you include the angular-cookies script after you included angular's main script? And of course both of those have to be before your application script.

Comment: yes the cookie script is after the angularjs script and before the main application script. it works perfectly on plunk.

Comment: do you see any errors in the console? I think you should upgrade your version of angular, use 1.2+.

Comment: <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.14/angular.min.js"></script> i am using this before angular cookies.

Comment: no errors on log check out this image http://imgur.com/veyExzq . I have just copied and pasted the code which you changed to two files.